# How to add OAuth server support in CAS server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Hello good afternoon I have a problem when wanting to run a cas server as oauth server, I followed all the steps of the source page to configure, but, I have problems at
redirect because it does not. It logs and validates authentication with cas but the redirect to origin (client) doesn't work, should do authorization and redirection oauth but is not executed.

Someone had this problem? could help me? I'm using version 3.5.2 of cas and oauth 2.0.

Comment: Are there any logs or error messages that you can include to help us find a solution?

Comment: Can you give us links to what steps you re following?

Comment: Excuse me, this is the link:

Comment: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+server+support

Comment: This is my url of my example, but is only in local: (http://localhost:8443/login?response_type=token&client_id=the_key_for_caswrapper1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61069%2Fauth_oauth%2Fsignin&scope=false&state=%7B%22d%22%3A%22demos%22%2C%22p%22%3A4%7D)